# Rest API response for api inside the extension module appends square bracket

Tags: php, rest-api

I have a rest api created in php. Sharing a sample here:

```
public function getApiData(){
$returnData = ["a"=>"A","b"=>"B"];
header("Content-Type: application/json");
// I want to return the data in the json format for which i have two options.
// Option 1:
return $returnData
// Option 2 (if i don't use the option 1 to return):
#jsonResponse = json_encode($returnData,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
print_r($jsonResponse);
}
```

For the option 1 the response is JSON but its just a string for ex:

"{\"a\":\"A\",\"b\":\"B.\"}"

For the option 2 the response is JSON but it's appended with square opening and closing bracket. ex:

```
{
 "a":"A",
"b":"B"
}[]
```

Notice that there is an opening and closing bracket in the end. If i use `die()` or `exit;` after the print_r statement then those square brackets are remove. But the problem is that i don't want to use both of them.

Is there any option to send pure JSON object in the response of rest API?

Postman response with the option 1
[image: Postman response with the option 1]

Answer (score 0):

Please do this

```
public function getApiData(){
$returnData = ["a"=>"A","b"=>"B"];

// Option 2 (if i don't use the option 1 to return):
$jsonResponse = json_encode($returnData,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
print_r($jsonResponse);

}
```

Comment: That is the problem, it returns incorrect json as explained by the output of option 2. It is appended by a [] square brackets.

Comment: Can you please check with
$jsonResponse = json_encode($returnData);

Comment: I tried with that too. Not working.

Comment: @Sudhir have you got the solution?

Comment: @usman sorry for the late reply. I didn't find any solution so had to do it the dirty way to remove ' [] '  from the end of the json on the consuming end. Since i had only one client as a consumer so i didn't had to look further.